# Mac only: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, java-11

I have a jar file of my application. 
When i run it using `java -cp "jarfile.jar" com.my.MainClass` it works just fine but if i give it to other devs, there is a clear case where i get this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.my.MainClass
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.my.MainClass
```

It is as such, only not working on Mac's. (Windows is fine)

Mac java version:

```
openjdk version “11.0.2” 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9, mixed mode)
```

Windows java version:

```
openjdk version "11" 2018-09-25
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11+28)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11+28, mixed mode)
```

I do not have any sun.* dependencies. Only finding dependencies under java.util, java.net, java.io, java.nioorg.junit (which is bundled in jar).

Will gladly give more info if necessary, just have no idea what is missing as such.

Comment: What Java code are you using?

Comment: Did you only share the jar or the class file as well? Did you test it on Windows machines other than your own? Did the Mac users set the directories correctly and did they run the java command from the correct location (the directory with the `com` subdiretory)?

Comment: the java code is quite simple. just running a small test reading the file basically. 
As for other windows machines yes i tried and it worked. Mac users are other java developers as well and have this setup for normal use. As for the directory yes it's  at the same level as the jar file is located in (which contains the com package)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this and ensure that you must be in parent folder of com directory
from your question MainClass is in following package hierarchy com->my->MainClass.java
and your class file MainClass.class also will present in same package hierarchy.

while running this MainClass you must be in parent directory of your com folder and try the following command for compile or run

in windows:-
for compile (ensure that you executing this command in parent folder for com directory)

javac -cp "jarfile.jar;." com\my\MainClass.java

java -cp "jarfile.jar;."  com.my.MainClass

for Mac or linux (ensure that you executing this command in parent folder for com directory)

javac -cp  "jarfile.jar:."   com/my/MainClass.java

java  -cp  "jarfile.jar:."   com.my.MainClass

Comment: it is not the parent folder that  was this issue but this answer saved me! on Windows the classpath is split by ; whereas on mac by :

Comment: @mangusbrother also note, in the original question you never mentioned the complete(actual) classpath used, so no one could have figured it out eventually(except you yourself).